# minitest: undefined method `get'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, minitest

I'm need to test my controller with minitest.
I've tried:

```
describe 'CommentsController' do
  it "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

and

```
class CommentsControllerTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_should_get_index
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

but I have "undefined method `get'" error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the [minitest-rails](http://blowmage.com/minitest-rails/) gem, following the steps outlined in the documentation. Then your tests should look like this:

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe CommentsController do
  it "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Or, look like this:

```
require "minitest_helper"

class CommentsControllerTest < MiniTest::Rails::ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe you can use `must_respond_with :success` expectation in the first example, above.

Comment: Depending on the version of minitest-rails you are using, yes.